# What is the difference when Rashi says בגמרא מפרש and מפרש בגמרא?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi

When Rashi comments on a Mishna telling us that the gemara will explain, sometimes he uses the phrase בגמרא מפרש and sometimes he uses the phrase מפרש בגמרא. (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.72a.10?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

Why would Rashi use one over the other (i.e. is there a difference in meaning)?

Comment: I've heard people say there is a difference, but personally I doubt it.

Comment: See Meiri on the first mishnah in Ketubot.

Comment: @N.T. So you're saying that Rashi, in two consecutive comments, changed his mind on how to say it?

Comment: @Alex What does that reference?

Comment: @Dani If there is no difference, it is not changing your mind.

Answer (score 8):

I heard in the name of the late Mirrer Rosh Yeshiva, Rav Nosson Tzvi Finkel zt"l, the following about the difference:

- The expression מפרש בגמרא is used to refer to an explanation for a local concept or word that the reader wouldn't know otherwise.
- The expression בגמרא מפרש is used to address a challenge that the reader might have.

I don't know what Rav Finkel's source was, but I have found this model to be helpful in my own learning.

Comment: If you look in the first mishne of beitsa. Bais shamai is first and bais hillel second as usual. But on whom does rashi say the gemoro has to explain.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but if one would apply Rav Finkel's approach to that Rashi it would be as follows: An egg laid on Yom Tov is not eaten according to Beis Hillel. Rashi writes it isn't eaten on that day and the gemara will explain why. The wording in Rashi is בגמרא מפרש because the reader has a challenge, "Why can't you eat the egg on Yom Tov?"

Comment: Since Bais Shamai is first in the mishna and the gemoro explains both Rashi ought to be on him. But since only Bais Hillell is difficult Rashi is on him.